# Variável não funciona no script

Tags: mysql

Srs, sou novo por aqui, estou sem resposta para saber o que está acontecendo.
Criei uma variável $rga para inserir através de um campo, mas não funciona.

Esse srcipt faz upload de foto e redimensiona.
Do modo exibido ele não aceita a variável $rga

Caso coloco as linhas

```
$rga = $_POST['rga'];
mysql_query("  UPDATE penpals SET picture = ' uploads/$filename ' WHERE ID = '$rga' ");
```

abaixo do `}`
Ai o problema passa a ser do `uploads/$filename` que não carrega a foto.
E a variável `$rga` passa a funcionar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
<?
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){   
   $pasta = 'uploads';
   $file = $_FILES['arquivo'];
   $temp = $file['tmp_name'];
   $filename = $file['name'];
    $largura_max    = 130;
   $altura_max  = 130;
   require ('redimensiona_fotos.php');
   $result = upload($temp, $filename, $largura_max, $altura_max, $pasta);
echo    "<img src=\"uploads/$filename\">"; 

$rga = $_POST['rga'];
mysql_query("  UPDATE penpals SET picture = ' uploads/$filename ' WHERE ID = '$rga' ");
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="arquivo">Arquivo:</label>
   <input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" /> 
   <br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Abrir imagem" />
</form>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<span class="add-on">User</span>
<input id="rga" name="rga" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Informe ID" />
<input class="form_botao" type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Precione para Enviar a FOTO - SALVE ABAIXO "><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigos pela dica..  já rosolvido.

Answer (score 0):

Você possui dois formulários (`<form>`). Ao clicar no botão submit de um, apenas os dados dele são submetidos. 
Se sua ideia é que o usuário submeta primeiro um formulário e depois outro, então você precisa fazer um código php para tratar cada chamada de formulário separadamente.
Do contrário, se sua ideia é que o usuário submeta apenas um formulário, você precisa eliminar um, e levar seus campos para o outro formulário, de modo que fique apenas um formulário com todos os campos.

Se atente para o `if($_POST['submit']){...}` Esse `'submit'` que você colocou, vem do seu `input name='submit'`. Quando mesclar seus formulários, você precisa manter esse input com esse name se quiser que esse if funcione.

Comment: Poderia modificar postando o exemplo ?

Comment: Já FUNCIONOU , OBRIGADO.    Se quiser ver como funciona, acesse www,rganimal.com.br